# Mocking anonymous function

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I'm writing jUnits and got stuck with the Lambda expressions.

Is there a way to mock anonymous function?

```
  return retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
     return mockedResponse;
  });
```

In the above code, I'm trying to mock `retryTemplate`.
`retryTemplate` is of type - `org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate`

Answer (score 5):

For me the solution of @encrest didn't work.

```
RetryTemplate mockRetryTemplate = Mockito.mock(RetryTemplate.class);
Mockito.when(mockRetryTemplate.execute(Matchers.any(RetryCallback.class))).thenReturn(mockedResponse);
```

I got this error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at test1(ServiceTest.java:41)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.


    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:164)
```

This error seems a bit stupid, because `.execute()` should work with only 1 argument (and thus 1 matcher). See also [non-sensical](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/193).

When looking into `RetryTemplate` sources, there are 4 `.execute()` methods. With one with 3 arguments. So I guess it is related to Matchers not being able to stub the right method.

Final solution:

```
RetryTemplate mockRetryTemplate = Mockito.mock(RetryTemplate.class);
Mockito.when(mockRetryTemplate.execute(Matchers.any(RetryCallback.class), Matchers.any(RecoveryCallback.class), Matchers.any(RetryState.class))).thenReturn(mockedResponse);
```

Can I add this to the original question: **Why isn't the Matcher able to resolve to the one-argument method?**

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I still have no freaking idea why that doesn't work. I didn't come up with this solution. Very nice, thanks!

Comment: *Why isn't the Matcher able to resolve to the one-argument method?* Problem is actually because, `RetryTemplate.execute` calls `doExecute` with your matcher object, and null for the rest. Which is not allowed because you can mix matchers and raw values

Answer (score 1):

Assuming 'retryTemplate' is a dependency in some bean "myBean", I would use dependency injection to mock the 'retryTemplate.execute' method using Mockito and configure it to accept any parameter:

```
RetryTemplate mockRetryTemplate = Mockito.mock(RetryTemplate.class);
Mockito.when(mockRetryTemplate.execute(Matchers.any(RetryCallback.class))).thenReturn(mockedResponse);
myBean.setRetryTemplate(mockRetryTemplate);
```

If I were just trying to mock a parameter to a method where the parameter happens to be a lambda, I would probably just create a new lambda expression stub rather than try to mock it.

Comment: execute method is not applicable for arguments (Object). It takes different sets of arguments.

Comment: @user1879835 try replacing Matchers.any() with Matchers.any(RetryCallback.class)