# JAVA mockito unit test for resttemplate and retryTemplate

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, resttemplate

I am currently writing unit test for below method

```
@Autowired
private RequestConfig requestConfig;

@Autowired
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

public ResponseEntity<String> makeGetServiceCall(String serviceUrl) throws Exception {
    try {
        return retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {

            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            HttpHeaders headers = requestConfig.createHttpHeaders();
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(serviceUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
            return response;

        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Generic exception while makeGetServiceCall due to" + e + serviceUrl);
    }
}
```

UPDATED METHOD:

```
@Autowired
private RequestConfig requestConfig;

@Autowired
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public ResponseEntity<String> makeGetServiceCall(String serviceUrl) throws Exception {
    try {
        return retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {

            HttpHeaders headers = requestConfig.createHttpHeaders();
            HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(serviceUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
            return response;

        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Generic exception while makeGetServiceCall due to" + e + serviceUrl);
    }
}
```

I tried all possibilities but I am unable to get it right. Here is my below test.

```
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Mock
public RequestConfig requestConfig;

@InjectMocks
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

ServiceRequest serviceRequest;


@Test
public void makeGetServiceCall() throws Exception {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080";
    RetryTemplate mockRetryTemplate = Mockito.mock(RetryTemplate.class);
    RestTemplate mockRestTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);
    ResponseEntity<String> myEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    Mockito.when(mockRetryTemplate.execute(ArgumentMatchers.any(RetryCallback.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(RecoveryCallback.class), ArgumentMatchers.any(RetryState.class))).thenReturn(myEntity);

    Mockito.when(mockRestTemplate.exchange(
            ArgumentMatchers.eq(url),
            ArgumentMatchers.eq(HttpMethod.GET),
            ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<String>>any(),
            ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any())
    ).thenReturn(myEntity);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = serviceRequest.makeGetServiceCall(url);
    Assert.assertEquals(myEntity, response);
}
```

UPDATED TEST CASE:

```
 @Mock
public RequestConfig requestConfig;

@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Mock
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

@InjectMocks
ServiceRequest serviceRequest;

@Test
public void makeGetServiceCall() throws Exception {
    //given:
    String url = "http://localhost:8080";

    when(requestConfig.createHttpHeaders()).thenReturn(null);
    ResponseEntity<String> myEntity = new ResponseEntity<>( HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    when(retryTemplate.execute(any(RetryCallback.class), any(RecoveryCallback.class), any(RetryState.class))).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        RetryCallback retry = invocation.getArgument(0);
        return retry.doWithRetry(/*here goes RetryContext but it's ignored in ServiceRequest*/null);
    });
    when(restTemplate.exchange(anyString(), any(HttpMethod.class), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(String.class)))
            .thenReturn(myEntity);

    //when:
    ResponseEntity<String> response = serviceRequest.makeGetServiceCall(url);

    //then:
    assertEquals(myEntity, response);
}
```

The response object which I get from my method call `makeGetServiceCall` always return null. When I debug the code I see exception `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:  ResponseEntity cannot be returned by toString() toString() should return String` error on the `resttemplate` mocking where I return `myEntity`

I am not sure what am I missing.

Comment: Why do you mock `RetryTemplate.execute(RetryCallback, RecoveryCallback, RetryState)` again??? That's why you get `null` as a result of calling `RetryTemplate.execute(RetryCallback)` in your `ServiceRequest`. Now if you replace 3-arg call with 1-arg call as in my answer, then you will get `myEntity` in response. Also, you can always check which method is called by adding `verify(retryTemplate, times(1)).execute(any(RetryCallback.class));` before assertion... and it'll succeed. Or if you add verification with 3 args then it will fail...

Comment: Thanks, I think that was the error. It works now.

Comment: Since you are only providing a callback in your service, mock is going to look for the other 2 parameters in the execute method as well (look at the source code for RetryTemplate). Use the following to make it work. `when(retryTemplate.execute(any(RetryCallback.class), isNull(), isNull()))...`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you have made quite some number of mistakes...

1. I'm sure you wanted to annotate `private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;` with `@Mock`, not `@InjectMocks`
2. `@InjectMocks` should go onto `ServiceRequest serviceRequest;`
3. You are defining interactions on some `mockRetryTemplate` and `mockRestTemplate` which have nothing to do with `serviceRequest`. Instead, you should use your `@Mock`-annotated fields to define interactions on because they are being injected into your object under test (`serviceRequest`)
4. Moreover, you can't normally mock `RestTemplate` and inject it into your `ServiceRequest` because you don't use dependency injection in the first place for `RestTemplate` in `ServiceRequest`. You just instantiate its instance in `ServiceRequest.makeGetServiceCall`
5. You are defining an interaction on the wrong method at line `Mockito.when(retryTemplate.execute(...`. Your interaction specifies `RetryTemplate.execute(RetryCallback, RecoveryCallback, RetryState)` whereas your `ServiceRequest` uses another method `RetryTemplate.execute(RetryCallback)`
6. You should also notice that `RetryTemplate.execute` is final and so you can't mock it without extra efforts as explained [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods). And generally, you should prefer interfaces over classes, e.g. `RestOperations` and `RetryOperations` over `RestTemplate` and `RetryTemplate` respectively, to be more flexible.

That said, below is the working test which solves your problem. But take note of removing `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();` from `ServiceRequest` and making `restTemplate` a field so it's dependency-injected.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceRequestTest {
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    public RequestConfig requestConfig;

    @Mock
    private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    ServiceRequest serviceRequest;

    @Test
    public void makeGetServiceCall() throws Exception {
        //given:
        String url = "http://localhost:8080";
        ResponseEntity<String> myEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        when(retryTemplate.execute(any(RetryCallback.class))).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
            RetryCallback retry = invocation.getArgument(0);
            return retry.doWithRetry(/*here goes RetryContext but it's ignored in ServiceRequest*/null);
        });
        when(restTemplate.exchange(eq(url), eq(HttpMethod.GET), any(HttpEntity.class), eq(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(myEntity);

        //when:
        ResponseEntity<String> response = serviceRequest.makeGetServiceCall(url);

        //then:
        assertEquals(myEntity, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But I am getting error for : `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 1 recorded:` on the parameters passed to the restTemplate exchange

Comment: @uday8486 have you tried my exact example? Looks like you are mixing matchers and values in `restTemplate` interaction, aren’t you? In my example I use only matchers

Comment: Yes, seems that we need to add 3 parameters, `retryTemplate.execute(any(RetryCallback.class), any(RecoveryCallback.class), any(RetryState.class)` something to with version of mockito I guess, got it from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173401/mocking-anonymous-function . But now I am getting assertion error, which I think makes sens as retry template will return null. But I am not sure how would I mock it to get what I expect.

Comment: @uday8486 which version of Mockito do you use? Have you checked my 6th point about mocking final methods? If you don't configure this, it won't be mocked and you will get assertion error. It had happened to me before I configured `mock-maker-inline`

Comment: I use version 2.8.47 of mockito, I was thinking that version 2+ would mock the final.

Comment: No, it doesn't unless you activate it. Check the [link](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#mock-the-unmockable-opt-in-mocking-of-final-classesmethods) from my point 6

Comment: I did these changes and added the mock maker inline `testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:2.13.0'` as well, but I get null response, i am expecting it to be a `ResponseEntity` object. Is it because the `context` is set to null in `RetryTemplate` mock?

Comment: No you are getting `null` not because of `context` being `null`. Did you remove `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();` from `ServiceRequest` and add `@Autowired private RestTemplate restTemplate;` to this class instead? So `restTemplate` is mocked as you expect. As I recommended in the 4th

Comment: I have updated the method and test in question. I have added the `RestTemplate` as dependency using `Autowired`

Comment: @uday8486 Did injecting the `RestTemplate` work. I am experiencing a similar thing where the `RetryTemplate` returns null regardless of what I do

Comment: It worked. But instead of null in `retry.doWithRetry()` I had to create new RetryContext in my case because the code uses context.

Answer (score 6):

For me below worked, otherwise, it was returning null always

```
when(retryTemplate.execute(any(),any(),any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
        RetryCallback retry = invocation.getArgument(0);
        return retry.doWithRetry(null);
});
```

and import was
`import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;`

Answer (score 0):

Generic solution:

```
Mockito.when(retryTemplate.execute(Matchers.any(),Matchers.any(),Matchers.any())).thenAnswer(invocation -> {
            RetryCallback retry = invocation.getArgumentAt(0,Matchers.any());
            return retry.doWithRetry(null);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me!

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RetryableRestClientTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private RetryableRestClient client;

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Test
    void test_get() {

        String url = "https://faked-url";

        ResponseEntity<String> expectedResponseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);

        Mockito.when(retryTemplate.execute(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()))
                .thenAnswer(invocation -> {
                    RetryCallback retry = invocation.getArgument(0);
                    return retry.doWithRetry(null);
                });

        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.eq(url), Mockito.eq(HttpMethod.GET), Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class), Mockito.eq(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(expectedResponseEntity);

        ResponseEntity<String> actualResponseEntity = client.get(url);

        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResponseEntity, actualResponseEntity);

    }
}

@Component
public class RetryableRestClient {

    @Autowired
    private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private HttpHeaders fakeHttpHeaders() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        // fake browser's behavior
        headers.add("authority", "m.nowscore.com");
        headers.add("cache-control", "max-age=0");
        headers.add("sec-ch-ua", "\" Not;A Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"91\", \"Chromium\";v=\"91\"");
        headers.add("sec-ch-ua-mobile", "?0");
        headers.add("upgrade-insecure-requests", "1");
        headers.add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36");
        headers.add("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
        headers.add("sec-fetch-site", "none");
        headers.add("sec-fetch-mode", "navigate");
        headers.add("sec-fetch-user", "?1");
        headers.add("sec-fetch-dest", "document");
        headers.add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
        return headers;
    }

    public final ResponseEntity<String> get(String url) {
        return retryTemplate.execute(context -> restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, new HttpEntity<>(null, fakeHttpHeaders()), String.class));
    }
}
```